# How to delete specific substrings of a pandas table that has strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file with 373 rows * 3 columns of data (I think by default its a DataFrame) and I used Pandas for this. 
At the end of some of the data frames there are some letters (substrings) that I'd like to be removed and later store this updated table under a new name. 
I had a lot of trouble doing it. I tried storing the columns of the table separately as strings and then replace these unwanted substrings will null (''). It didn't work and now I'm lost! Please help!!
This is what I tried: Splitting of the tables into columns and then replacing

```
import pandas as pd

loss=pd.read_csv('Loss.csv')

eq1_list=str(loss.ix[:,0])

eq2_list=str(loss.ix[:,1])

eq3_list=str(loss.ix[:,2])

for eq in eq1_list:
    eq.replace('.fail','')
    eq.replace('.fail2','')

print(eq1_list)
```

As you can see '.fail' and '.fail2' are the substrings in the pandas table and these substrings are present in many elements in the whole 373*3 table. This method didn't delete the substrings.
Sample input:

```
     EQ1     EQ2        EQ3
0    A1.fail A2.fail    NaN
1    B1.fail2 B3.fail   B3.fail2
...
372  X1.fail  X2.fail2  X3.fail
```

Expected output:

```
A1 A2 NaN
B1 B3 B3
...
X1 X2 X3
```

Comment: Please provide sample input data, and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way easier than you think using [DataFrame.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
new_loss = loss.replace('\.fail.?$', '', regex=True)
```

This will remove any string suffix matching ".failX", where X can be anything (or nothing).

The replace method is extremely powerful and has many options. I encourage you to read the doc (linked above).

Comment: To replace .fail2 you can run the line twice, but I suggest you read on how to replace 2 strings at the same time.

Comment: Hello, I tried what you said @Shovalt . But it didn't work.

Comment: @VachanBhat you are correct. I didn't test the code before but now I fixed and tested and it's working. It turns out that without enabling regex the replace method only replaces exact matches (not partial strings). Give it a go.